# How to call function every second in Kivy python

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I don't understand how to call function every second in Kivy. There are little examples in docs. I want to make an application with music player and I should to update slider value every second when music plays, I also don't use `kivy.audio` but `pygame`. My `playing` fuction is starting every second, but the program crushes.

```
class Player(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Player, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.file = 'music_files/muzlome_Billie_Eilish_-_Ocean_Eyes_47841905.mp3'
        self.play = 'images/play.png'
        self.palki = 'images/palki.png'
        self.cursor = 'images/cursor.png'
        pygame.init()
        pygame.mixer.music.load(self.file)
        self.sound = SoundLoader.load(self.file)
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
        pygame.mixer.music.pause()
        pygame.mixer.music.set_pos(100)
        self.position = pygame.mixer.music.get_pos() // 1000
        self.f = 1

        self.sl = Slider(orientation='horizontal',
                         min=0,
                         max=self.sound.length,
                         value=(pygame.mixer.music.get_pos() // 1000),
                         step=1,
                         padding=20,
                         background_width=40,
                         value_track=True,
                         value_track_color=(1, .1, .1, 1),
                         value_track_width=(5),
                         cursor_image=(self.cursor),

                         )
        self.sl.bind(value=self.slider_callback)
        self.w1.add_widget(self.sl)
        but1 = Button()
        self.but2 = Button(background_normal=(self.play),
                           background_down=(self.palki),
                           on_press=self.play_but_callback,
                           )
        but3 = Button()
        self.gl.add_widget(but1)
        self.gl.add_widget(self.but2)
        self.gl.add_widget(but3)
        self.lb = Label(font_size=35,
                        size_hint_x=.85,
                        text=to_seconds(self.sl.value),
                        halign='right',
                        valign='top'
                        )
        self.al.add_widget(self.lb)

    def slider_callback(self, intance, value):
        print(value)
        self.position = value
        self.lb.text = to_seconds(value)
        pygame.mixer.music.rewind()
        pygame.mixer.music.set_pos(self.position)

    def playing(self, dt):
        if self.but2.background_normal == self.palki:
            self.position = pygame.mixer.music.get_pos() // 1000
            self.sl.value = self.position

    def play_but_callback(self, intance):
        if intance.background_normal == self.play:
            intance.background_normal = self.palki
            intance.background_down = self.palki
            self.f = 0
            pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
            self.sl.value = self.position
            #self.event = Clock.schedule_interval(self.playing, 0.5)
        else:
            pygame.mixer.music.pause()
            intance.background_normal = self.play
            intance.background_down = self.play
            self.f = 1
            #self.event.cancel()

class Audio_Player(App):
    def build(self):
        p = Player()
        Clock.schedule_interval(p.playing, 1)
        return p

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Audio_Player().run()
```

Comment: So...why does it crash? Always post the full traceback if possible.

Comment: Also your repeated calls to `Player()` all create a new instance of the class, rather than using the current/existing instance. This is totally wrong, your app won't work right at all, although it might sort of work by coincidence.

Comment: Sory, It is not crush but  runs so slowly. I should replace Player() to 'self ' in my playing(). Am I correct? It doesn't work for some reason. " float type object has no attribute 'but2' ". Please offer your solution. Sory my English

Comment: Sounds like your original problem is the infinite numbers of Player instances you were creating. Having resolved that, please give full details about the new problem (full traceback, new code).

Comment: Ohh yes it's working. Thank you for your help. But I have other problem now, when I move slider, track restarts with new value and just after restarts with old position. I think it is pygame's problem. Can you help me?

Comment: I have editted the question