# How to make sure a kivy app can connect to a database before executing (and check the connection on runtime)

Tags: python, kivy, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I have a kivy app that needs to connect to a certain database which is hosted on a certain Ip address on my raspberry pi which is accessible via WiFi.

Thats why my app crashes if I connect to another WiFi or if there is no WiFi. How can I make it so that I show a different page where the user can try to reconnect to the database with a button if the connection was not successfully established.

I would also want a popup when there is a WiFi problem while using the app.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple questions in one:

- Python: How to check if we are connected to internet ? https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-check-internet-connection-in-python
- Python: How to check which wifi we are connected to ? "idk"
- Python: How to connect to an ip adress ? "idk"
- Kivy: How to show a new page ? https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html
- Kivy: How to add a button ? https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.button.html
- Kivy: How to make a function being used when we click on a button ? https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.button.html
- Kivy: How to make a function being used every x seconds ? [How to call function every second in Kivy python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59444798/how-to-call-function-every-second-in-kivy-python)
- Kivy: How to create a popup ? https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.popup.html

Focus is the key.